# MediaSource does not work with supported codecs

Tags: javascript, video-streaming, html5-video, media-source, video-codecs

I tried to work with `MediaSource`, but it works only with the video file from the MDN example.

Although `MediaSource.isTypeSupported(mimeCodec)` returns `true` for videos which I tested, the videos are not showed anyway.

Here is the videos I used list with comments:

```js
// Only with this video it works
var assetURL = 'https://nickdesaulniers.github.io/netfix/demo/frag_bunny.mp4';
var mimeCodec = 'video/mp4; codecs="avc1.42E01E, mp4a.40.2"'; // ./mp4info frag_bunny.mp4 | grep Codec

// It does not work
var assetURL = 'https://giant.gfycat.com/HandmadeMajesticIndianjackal.mp4';
var mimeCodec = 'video/mp4; codecs="avc1.64002A, mp4a.40.2"';

// The previous video, but encoded by Youtube. The same codecs, but reduced size. (it does not work too)
var assetURL = 'https://giant.gfycat.com/NaturalBraveHoneycreeper.mp4';
var mimeCodec = 'video/mp4; codecs="avc1.64002A, mp4a.40.2"';


// Another random not working examples:

// var assetURL = 'https://giant.gfycat.com/DigitalPolishedDassie.mp4';
// var mimeCodec = 'video/mp4; codecs="avc1.640033"';

// var assetURL = 'https://giant.gfycat.com/AncientAllAmericanavocet.mp4';
// var mimeCodec = 'video/mp4; codecs="avc1.42C01F"';
```

The short example.
It works fine only with the first video.

(Check the full demo below.)

```js
let video = document.querySelector("video");
let mediaSource = new MediaSource();
video.src = URL.createObjectURL(mediaSource);
mediaSource.addEventListener("sourceopen", sourceOpen);

async function sourceOpen(_) {
  const mediaSource = this;
  const sourceBuffer = mediaSource.addSourceBuffer(mimeCodec);

  const resp = await fetch(assetURL);  
  const reader = resp.body.getReader();
  let updated = Promise.resolve();
  while (true) {    
    const {done, value} = await reader.read();
    await updated;
    if (done) {
      break;
    }
    sourceBuffer.appendBuffer(value);
    updated = sourceBufferUpdated(sourceBuffer);    
  }
  reader.releaseLock();
  mediaSource.endOfStream();
  await video.play();
};

function sourceBufferUpdated(sourceBuffer) {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    if (sourceBuffer.updating) {        
      sourceBuffer.onupdate = resolve;
    } else {
      resolve();
    }
  });
}
```

The full "working" demo. Click the "next" button.

```js
const entries = [
    {
        url: 'https://nickdesaulniers.github.io/netfix/demo/frag_bunny.mp4',
        // ./mp4info frag_bunny.mp4 | grep Codec
        mimeCodec: 'video/mp4; codecs="avc1.42E01E, mp4a.40.2"'
    }, {
        url: 'https://giant.gfycat.com/HandmadeMajesticIndianjackal.mp4',
        mimeCodec: 'video/mp4; codecs="avc1.64002A, mp4a.40.2"'
    }, {
        url: 'https://giant.gfycat.com/NaturalBraveHoneycreeper.mp4',
        mimeCodec: 'video/mp4; codecs="avc1.64002A, mp4a.40.2"'
    }, {
        url: 'https://giant.gfycat.com/DigitalPolishedDassie.mp4',
        mimeCodec: 'video/mp4; codecs="avc1.640033"'
    }, {
        url: 'https://giant.gfycat.com/AncientAllAmericanavocet.mp4',
        mimeCodec: 'video/mp4; codecs="avc1.42C01F"'
    }
];

let index = 0;
main(entries[index]);

function main({url, mimeCodec}) {
    document.querySelector("#url").textContent = url;
    document.querySelector("#mimeCodec").textContent = mimeCodec;

    if (!MediaSource.isTypeSupported(mimeCodec)) {
        document.querySelector("#mimeCodec").textContent += " (mimeCodec is not supported)";
        return;
    }

    const video = document.querySelector("video");
    const mediaSource = new MediaSource();
    video.src = URL.createObjectURL(mediaSource);
    mediaSource.addEventListener("sourceopen", sourceOpenHandler);

    async function sourceOpenHandler() {
        const mediaSource = this;
        const sourceBuffer = mediaSource.addSourceBuffer(mimeCodec);

        const resp = await fetch(url);
        const reader = resp.body.getReader();
        let updated = Promise.resolve();
        while (true) {
            const {done, value} = await reader.read();
            await updated;
            if (done) {
                break;
            }
            sourceBuffer.appendBuffer(value);
            updated = sourceBufferUpdated(sourceBuffer);
        }
        reader.releaseLock();
        mediaSource.endOfStream();

        await video.play();
    };
}

function sourceBufferUpdated(sourceBuffer) {
    return new Promise(resolve => {
        if (sourceBuffer.updating) {
            sourceBuffer.onupdate = resolve;
        } else {
            resolve();
        }
    });
}

document.querySelector("body").addEventListener("click", event => {
    if (event.target.id === "next") {
        ++index;
    } else if (event.target.id === "pre") {
        --index;
    } else {
        return;
    }

    const {length} = entries;
    const possition = (length + (index % length)) % length;
    main(entries[possition]);
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <title>MediaSourse Demo</title>
  </head>
  <body>  
    <button id="pre">pre</button>
    <button id="next">next</button>
    <div id="mimeCodec"></div>
    <div id="url"></div>

    <video controls="" src="" crossorigin="anonymous" muted></video>
    <script src="script.js"></script>

  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Are those videos fragmented? Check: [Transcoding assets for Media Source Extensions > Checking Fragmentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Media_Source_Extensions_API/Transcoding_assets_for_MSE#Checking_Fragmentation)

Comment: I thought if the browser can show a part of the video during downloading _(even without specifying of the codecs)_, then I can emulate the same behaviour with `MediaSource` (I want to download videos with `fetch`). Well, I thought the problem was that it requires to specify codecs. But it also requires a special container format (I guess). Okay, this API is not as good as I expected.

Comment: Yeah, I have rechecked it with mp4 that was encoded by Youtube, but this time I used only the video row. And it works. In my example I used the concatenation of the mp4 video with mp4a audio, so the result was a mp4 file that is a "common", not special, mp4.

Comment: Well, but how, for example, Youtube uses `MediaSource` with **not** fragmented videos?